# Override KMZ/KML icons for a google.maps.kmlLayer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I am writing a mobile angular javascript app that receives a message.  The message contains some metadata about the message and also a url which points to a kmz file.  Currently I use that kmz url to display a kmllayer via google maps inside my app.

```
kmlLayers[i] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                        url: kmlURLs[i],
                        suppressInfoWindows: false,
                        map: $scope.map
                });
```

The kml currently contains style information similar to this:

```
<Icon>
    <href>root://icons/palette-4.png</href>
    <x>32</x>
    <y>128</y>
    <w>32</w>
    <h>32</h>
  </Icon>
```

I would like to override the Icon for this layer based on metadata that I receive in my inbound message. So instead of seeing a pushpin, I show an icon such as a store icon or a post office icon.  Is there a recommended way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can't be done with [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions) (at least at present).  If you control the KML/KMZ, the simplest option would be to change it to specify the icon you want.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case, I'm thinking we have to parse and modify the KML we receive.  Thanks!